# WPF RichTextBox Touch Scrolling doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a rich text box control, that I wish to be able to scroll by touch.

The MSDN documentation says I should set this property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" >
```

However, this makes no difference, touch events still select text and instead of scrolling. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to modify your tag as follows. `<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.PanningMode="Both" ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration="20" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So creating a scrollable object is a bit tricky in WPF. You need to put the `RichTextBox` inside the `ScrollViewer`. Then you need to set the `PanningMode` to either `horizontal` or `vertical` (or you can try to set it to auto which is also recommended). For example you should get something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
            <RichTextBox> 
                       //content here
            </RichTextBox>
</Scrollviewer>
```